# Getting low Host-Device transfer rate with NVIDIA Quadro M4000

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I am doing OpenCL on an NVIDIA Quadro M4000 installed on PCIe 3x16. On the card documentation, it is stated that the transfer rate CPU->GPU can go up to 15.7Gb/s while on my benchmark it is yielding only ~2.4Gb/s. I know that effective transfer rate can significantly differ from theoretical one but I wasn't expecting the difference to be that much.

Anyone has any experience with the quadro CPU->GPU data transfer.

Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>
#include<CL/cl.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

SYSTEMTIME last_call;

cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_platform;
cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_device;
cl_context context = NULL;
cl_command_queue command_queue = NULL;
cl_program program = NULL;
cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
cl_int err;

void _profile(char* msg){
SYSTEMTIME tmp;

clFinish(command_queue);

GetSystemTime(&tmp);
printf("__Profile --- %s --- : %d : %d : %d\n", msg, (tmp.wMinute - last_call.wMinute),
    (tmp.wSecond - last_call.wSecond),
    (tmp.wMilliseconds - last_call.wMilliseconds));
    last_call = tmp;
}

int main()
{

// Reading Kernel Program
char *kernel_src_std = "__kernel void copy(__global const uchar *x,  __global uchar *z){\
                       const int id = get_global_id(0);\
                       z[id] = x[id];   \
                       }";
size_t kernel_src_size = strlen(kernel_src_std);

// Create Input data
int w = 1920;
int h = 1080;
int c = 3;

float* input = (float*)malloc(w * h * c * sizeof(float));   
for(int i=0;i<w*h*c;i++)
    input[i] = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;


// getting platform ID
err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platform);

// Get Device ID
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_device );

// Create Context
context = clCreateContext(NULL,1,&device_id,NULL,NULL,&err);

// Create Command Queue
command_queue =  clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);

// Create buffer Object
cl_mem buf_in = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(float) * w*h*c,
    0, &err);

cl_mem buf_out = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * w*h*c,
    0, &err);

_profile("Start transfer input...");

// Copy Data from Host to Device
cl_event event[5];

err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,buf_in,CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*w*h*c,input,0,NULL, NULL);

_profile("End transfer input...");

// Create and Build Program
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&kernel_src_std, 0, &err);

// Create Kernel
kernel = clCreateKernel(program,"copy",&err );

// Set Kernel Arguments

err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&buf_in);

err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1,sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&buf_out);

// Execute Kernel 
size_t ws[]={h*w*c};
size_t lws[]={100};
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, ws, lws, 0, NULL, NULL);

// Create output buf
float* output = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*w*h*c);

// Read output Data, from Device to Host
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, buf_out, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*w*h*c, output,NULL,NULL,NULL);


//Release Objects

clReleaseMemObject(buf_in);
clReleaseMemObject(buf_out);
clReleaseKernel(kernel);
clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
clReleaseContext(context);
free(input);
free(output);

while(1);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: It can depend on how you transfer the data. How do you do it? Is it just one huge array that you move to the GPU? Also: have you compared your results with the benchmark given in the CUDA examples?

Comment: Yes, I am transferring an array of 6220800 float. Could that be the reason? I could not find the OpenCL examples on my install. People seem to say that NVIDIA isn t maintaining those anymore. I transfer using clEnqueueWriteBuffer.

Comment: @lity This question seems to be about OpenCL, yet is also tagged [cuda]. I would suggest removing that tag to avoid confusion. Make sure the card is plugged into a PCIe x16 slot, not a PCIe x4 slot. Maximum real-life transfer rate for PCIe gen3 x16 is about 11-12 GB/sec for transfer sizes >= 16 MB. You need to use "pinned memory" on the host for maximum transfer speed, not sure whether OpenCL supports that.

Comment: Thanks Njuffa, tag is removed. I am sure my card is on a 3x16 PCIe slot. OpenCL allows the device to create and "pin" memory on the host via the flag CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR. Now I have tried that, the transfer between host and device is slightly faster (~4.2GB/s, so nowhere near the 12GB/s)

Comment: Please post the code you used for benchmarking. And why did you pinned the memory on the host when you actually want to transfer data to the device?

Comment: I have edited my post and add my benchmarking code. I am using the CPU timer in the _profile function which basically at each call display the time elapsed since the last call.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

As your question is vague it is hard to pinpoint the exact reason for your poor performance. Some concrete code *might* help.

However, in your comments you say that you transfer an array of 6220800 floats. That is about 200 megabits to transfer. At maximum transfer rate (15.7Gb/s) that should give about 12ms.

However, with every new transfer request there is also a *latency* that is added, which --- for small transfers --- can effectively degrade your transfer rate.

Have you tried benchmarking on significantly bigger arrays (say, 100x the size)?

Comment: Oh sorry, I miss-typed: the transfer rate is actually 15.7GB/s (instead of Gb/s). So the expected transfer time should be ~1.7ms.
I have tried with bigger array(100x) and still having the same rate.
This is the piece of code I use for the transfer:  

`result = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cl.command_queue, kernel.kernel_inputs[i].data, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * kernel.kernel_inputs[i].size, kernel.inputs[i].data, 0 , NULL, NULL);` 

Thanks

Comment: You cant measure transfer speeds with blocking calls and in the CPU side. You should use clEvents. That way of measurements is bogus, may give you any result depending on the latency between CPU and GPU in triggering the callback.

Comment: I think you can. In the NVDIA OpenCL best practice it using CPU timer on opencl blocking command call is one of the two profiling methods proposed (chapter 2.1)

Answer (score 1):

You're using blocking transfers which means you're incurring a stall on the read/write requests (additionally you're not using pinned memory, but you addressed that). At the moment, your code goes

Begin timing -> Write -> stall -> kernel -> read -> stall -> end timing. This will drastically affect the timings for your memory bandwidth transfer if your transfer scale is on the order of 2ms, as the stalls are comparable in size to this. You'll need to eliminate these stalls if you want to measure the bandwidth accurately